# How to execute Bulk Insert Stored Procedure inside Controller

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

i have written a stored procedure for bulk insert like this:

```
USE [BRDCEP_MIS]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create proc dbo.SP_BulkInsertPsc
as
begin
BULK INSERT BrdcepPscData 
FROM  'E:\BRDCEP_MIS\BRDCEP_MIS\App_Data\PSC\NRSP.csv'
WITH 
( 
     FIRSTROW = 2 ,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
)
end
GO
```

and i want to execute this SP when i call the specific function in the controller it shows no error but also it is not adding data into the database . my controller function is this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ImportPSCData()
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE BrdcepPscData");
        var a = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>("Sp_BulkInsertPsc");
    }

    return View();
}
```

can anybody please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: `'E:\BRDCEP_MIS\BRDCEP_MIS\App_Data\PSC\NRSP.csv'` Is it path from local machine?

Comment: yes it works fine when i run it as a simple query it doesn't give any error

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to upload data to your SQL server as a one-off, you can use the [Sql Server Import Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard).

If you are creating an application that features a bulk-upload facility, you can use the [Bulk Copy Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx). This allows you to map columns in your SQL database to a .CSV file.